# Hyperbola / Rotated Hyperbola Intersection

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to find the point where two hyperbolas intersect, that is, to find a vertex that is common to both hyperbolas.

Also, note that I am only testing for a region of both hyperbolas -- only a quarter of each (either $-b/a$, $b/a$, $-a/b$ or $a/b$).

Here is what I have so far for getting any vertex on a hyperbola:
$(x,y)=(a\ cosh(r),b\ sinh(r))$

Now suppose I have two hyperbolas:
-one at the origin $(h,k)=(0,0)$ and not rotated($t=0$)
-one not at the origin $(h,k)=(3,10)$ and rotated ($t=\pi/4$)

How would you go about and compare the two?

My guess is to start with something like this:
$(a_1cosh(r_1),b_1sinh(r_1))=(a_2cosh(r_2),b_2sinh(r_2))$

And then isolate $r_1$ and $r_2$, but then what does it look like when a translation and rotation is involved?

Or maybe I am completely off track.

Comment: Likely the intersection formula is going to give you your best answer (better than a numerical approximation algorithm), so, yes, this should probably go in Math. Also, you should simply give the two formulas for your hyperbolas after transformation, the domain you are considering, and ask for a derivation of the intersection formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following two hyperbolas:

The canonical equation of a hyperbola is:

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
```

Now, let's consider two hyperbolas:

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
x^2/c^2 + y^2/d^2 = 1
```

You determine `y^2` based on `x^2` from the first equation:

```
y^2 = b^2(1 - x^2/a^2)
```

You use this information in the second equation:

```
x^2/c^2 + b^2(1 - x^2/a^2)/d^2 = 1
```

From here:

```
x^2/c^2 + b^2/d^2 - (b^2/(a^2 * d^2))x^2 = 1
```

Therefore:

```
(a^2 * d^2 - b^2 * c^2)x^2/(a^2 * c^2 * d^2) = 1 - b^2/d^2
```

Finally:

```
x^2 = ((1 - b^2) / d^2) * ((a^2 * c^2 * d^2) / (a^2 * d^2 - b^2 * c^2))
```

Simplifying it:

```
x^2 = ((1 - b^2) * a^2 * c^2) / (a^2 * d^2 - b^2 * c^2))
```

You can now calculate the square root of `x` and use it for `y^2` as well, finally square root `y`. Do not forget the +- values.